# How to use mediawiki API to create a table for a wiki page in PHP

Tags: php, line-breaks, tabular, mediawiki-api

I intend to use MediaWiki API to create a table for a wiki page. In MediaWiki, the syntax for creating a table should be like the following:

```
{|class="wikitable sortable"
!'''Full Name'''||'''Short Name'''
|-
|MediaWiki||MW
|}
```

When I called MediaWiki API, I stored the contents which I want to add to the page in a string:

```
$content = "{|class='wikitable sortable'<br>!'''Full Name'''||'''Short Name'''<br>|-<br>|MediaWiki||MW|}";
```

I intended to used "br" to make line breaks, but failed to create a table. Without line breaks, a table can't be showed either. How can I make line breaks before I call MediaWiki API?

Comment: You need to insert not an HTML line break, but an actual newline character, as in `"\n"`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have tried that, but the HTML tag will be showed in edit box, which can't help to create a table correctly. What I want is to make line breaks before calling MediaWiki API and the contents will be showed with break lines in the "edit box".