# How to make line breaks for a string or plain text

Tags: php, line-breaks, tabular, mediawiki-api

I intend to use MediaWiki API to create a table for a wiki page. In MediaWiki, the syntax for creating a table should be like the following:

```
{|class="wikitable sortable"
!'''Full Name'''||'''Short Name'''
|-
|MediaWiki||MW
|} //line breaks must be made
```

When I called MediaWiki API, I stored the contents in a string:

```
$content = "{|class='wikitable sortable'!'''Full Name'''||'''Short Name'''|-|MediaWiki||MW|}";
```

The string will be used as one parameters when MediaWiki API is called, and it will be as the editing contents for that wiki page. I intended to used "br" or "\n" to make line breaks, but failed to create a table. Without line breaks, a table can't be showed either. How can I make line breaks before I call MediaWiki API?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use mediawiki API to create a table for a wiki page in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940674/how-to-use-mediawiki-api-to-create-a-table-for-a-wiki-page-in-php)

Comment: Yes. I posted both of the questions. I supposed this one can be easier to be understood since MediaWiki API seems not widely used.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
&lt;br /&gt;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what each of those are?

Comment: encoded characters. Since he stated that <br> was not working, I thought that maybe the API would decode the characters upon loading the table. Qouted: "The predefined characters are:

& (ampersand) becomes &amp;
" (double quote) becomes &quot;
' (single quote) becomes &#039;
< (less than) becomes &lt;
> (greater than) becomes &gt;"

So &lt;br /&gt; would make <br />
I wonder if it worked

Comment: Thank you for replying. I want to handle the string to make line breaks before calling the API. How can I make the format satisfying the syntax showing above and pass it as a parameter?